# Route returning 404 NOT FOUND for /about-us in Laravel. How to resolve it?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

PHP Version - 8.2.4
Laravel 10

I am facing an issue with one of the routes in my Laravel application. I have defined a route for the '/about-us' URL, but whenever I try to access it, I get a 404 NOT FOUND error. I've spent some time debugging it, but I can't seem to figure out what's causing the problem.

Here's the code for the route in my web.php file:

```
Route::get('/about-us', [SiteController::class, 'about'])->name('about-us');
```

And here's the corresponding method in the SiteController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\TextWidget;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function about(): View
    {
        $widget = TextWidget::query()
            ->where('key', '=', 'about-page')
            ->where('active', '=', 1)
            ->first();

        return view('about', compact('widget'));
    }
}
```

All other routes are functioning as expected.

I have also checked the database, and there is a record with the key 'about-page' and 'active' set to 1 in the 'TextWidget' table.

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance!

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I also Cleared the Route Cache and checked.
Restarted the Development Server but not working.

Comment: Looks ok to me! And the URL that is triggering this `HTTP 404` is `http://localhost:8000/about-us`? If you run `php artisan route:list`, do you see `/about-us` in that list? Is there any middleware, or is this in a `Route::group`?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/about-us

GET|HEAD   about-us ................................ about-us › SiteController@about

Comment: `dd($widget);`, but first: do a `dd("here");` right above the $widget. I think you're query should be a bit different. I also would dl `findOrFail()`

Answer (score -1):

To solve the problem, proceed as follows:

1- There is no need to use / at the beginning to define the route, and the route name should be written as follows:

```
Route::get('about-us', [SiteController::class, 'about'])->name('about.us');
```

or

```
Route::get('about-us', [SiteController::class, 'about'])->name('aboutus');
```

2- Then enter the following command in the terminal to make sure the route is defined in Laravel.This command will show you the list of all routes defined in Laravel:

```
php artisan route:list
```

> If you see your route in the list, it means that your route is defined
> in Laravel.

3- Make sure all caches are cleared by entering this command in the terminal:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

4- Now call your route. If you encounter a 404 error again, proceed as follows:

> Move the route you created in the web.php file and move it to the
> beginning of the list of defined routes or to the end of it and repeat
> step 3 again.

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

Sure, here's a condensed version of the steps to check and clear the Laravel route cache:

**1. Check Route Cache:**
Navigate to bootstrap/cache and check for a file named routes.php to see if your routes are cached.

**2. Clear Route Cache:**
In your project's root directory, run:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

To clear other caches too, use:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

After clearing the cache, test you

Answer (score -2):

Probably you have to check if the view name Is 'about' and if the view 'about' Is in another folder in the views folder. Remember that if you use the same call method on the same Route you could have problems too. Maybe you could try to avoid to write 'public function about(): View' and write instead 'public function about(){}'.

Comment: None of what you suggested would fix an `HTTP 404` error; if the view is missing (either not there, or named wrong, etc.), you get the error `View [...] not found.`. `public function about(): View` is valid with or without `: View`, that's simply type hinting that the method should return a `View` class, which `return view(...)` does (and there's no other `return` statements in that code). Sorry, but this answer is not the solution.